# Auditing Domain Administrators - Best practice / Advice needed please

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, audit

Please do advise if I am posting in the wrong place, I have not found this the easiest site to navigate (or maybe it is me...).

I have been tasked with auditing and fixing our privileged accounts after a Microsoft CSAT scan. I have inherited an absolutely shocking number of accounts that are 'affective domain administrators' - 293!

It seems the previous attitude has been security anethema - giive service accounts Domain Admin status to ensure they are not part of the problem... *sigh*

I have investigated numerous powershell options and come to the conclusion that I need to:

1. Find out which SERVERS each account is authenticating against (Inluding DCs obviously).
2. Find out the *least required* access for each server.
3. Amend access accordingly and test.

Would anyone be able to advise on the best way to proceed please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to secure this amount of admin accounts without creating a downtime. So first thing first - make sure your manager has adequate expectations - things will break in the process.

Comment: You'll want to start with enabling AD auditing on the DCs to identify which areas of the directory these accounts are making changes. Also implement a restricted groups GPO to move away from using Domain Admins for local administrator access and to groups with more granular access. Then you can start moving these accounts into a lesser privileged group and delegate directory access where necessary.